# noHandlerFound in Spring for CSS

Tags: java, html, css, spring

I am learning Spring MVC and I try to get some experience. I wrote an app and deployed it to Tomcat serve. At run time, the browser gets a 404 code for the CSS and Tomcat "WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-12] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.noHandlerFound No mapping for GET /SpringC5BuildingSpringWebApplication/resources/style.css"
Can you please give me some hints of what could be wrong?
Below is my code:

> App initializer

```
public class SpittrWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] {"/"};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] {RootConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] {WebConfig.class};
}
```

}

> WebConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = HomeController.class)        
class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport{
    
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = 
                new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

> Controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

> Webpage

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Spitter</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
              href="<c:url value="/resources/style.css" />" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to Spitter</h1>

        <a href="<c:url value="/spittles" />">Spittles</a> | 
        <a href="<c:url value="/spitter/register" />">Register</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

> WebXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd"
     version="3.0">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

> [Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3LN4.jpg)

The CSS file is inserted in many places with the home that the server will read it from somewhere. Any hint could be helpful and appreciated! Thank you and I wish you good health!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the WebConfig.class.
I need to change the inherited entity. From `class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport` to `public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer`.